# Lost site administrator privileges for wordpress admin account on appengine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I installed wordpress on appengine and deployed it.  After installing the batcache and google appengine plugins, and creating a cloud storage bucket as described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

I find that I no longer have administrator privileges for my admin account on the deployed wordpress.  I do not see an option for installing themes, which I did see earlier.

However, I continue to have administrator privileges for my local development version running in my machine.

I assume this has to do with some appengine settings, but I can't figure out what I must tweak.

Does this have to do with the bucket permissions I set up to enable the last bit in the URL above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Can you still sign in as admin?

If so:
Installing themes when it runs on AE isn't possible, unfortunately, because you don't have write permissions to the server. The workaround is to install configure all themes etc. locally, and then re-upload them to the server. It's not as convenient as being able to do it 'live' while online, but it still works.

If not:
You could delete the online database for wordpress and recreate it, which I believe will take you through the online setup for your blog again. You could then create a new admin.

Hope that helps.